# Redirect form options to custom URL JS

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect, onclick

The following code works perfectly when working from the base domain, when I insert on any page (WP structure) inherits its name:

```
http://domainname/pagename/pieze1pieze2pieze3

<ul>
<li><a id="LNK" href="##" value="value1" onclick="clickLink(this)">Value1</a></li>
<li><a id="LNK" href="##" value="value2" onclick="clickLink(this)">Value2</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
function clickLink(a) {
       var pieze1 = a.getAttribute('value');
       var pieze2 = custom_1;
       var pieze3 = custom_2;
       window.open(pieze1+pieze2+pieze3);
       return false;
    }
</script>
```

Any ideas? thnk

Comment: Why not directly do a redirect using javascript?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have little knowledge of javascript, I start now with search.

Comment: It will save you a request to the server, everything is done on the clients machine. Much better...

Comment: I edit de question Mr. White

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is wrong. Remove

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO TO THE URL"><br>
```

from within the  and place it outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Done!!

```
<ul>
<li><a id="LNK" href="#" value="value_option_a" onclick="clickLink(this)">LINK_OPTION_A</a></li>
<li><a id="LNK" href="#" value="value_option_b" onclick="clickLink(this)">LINK_OPTION_B</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
function clickLink(a) {
    var link_option_list_value = a.getAttribute('value');
    var custom_url_one = '(custom url part one)';
    var custom_url_two = (custom url part two);
    window.location.assign("http://domainbase/"+link_option_list_value+custom_url_one+custom_url_two)
    return false;
    }
</script>
```